# Intent on setOnInfoWindowClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent, dictionary, marker

I'm doing a bus tracker app and I wanted the app to display another activity when I clicked the marker. For example the bus stop. When I clicked it, it would bring me to another activity (**businfo.xml**) and show the information about the bus stop. I'm trying to use intent but no luck. It gives me this error. "*The constructor Intent(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener(){}, Class) is undefined*" The quick fix would be "*remove arguments to match Intent()*".

P.S. Please check if I'm right by doing *.setOnInfoWindowClickListener* instead of *setOnMarkerClickListener*. The eclipse brings me error when I use *setOnMarkerClickListener*.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;

import com.example.unitenbustracker.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(2.962584, 101.725738);



    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mapCenter, 163));

    // Flat markers will rotate when the map is rotated,
    // and change perspective when the map is tilted.
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .position(mapCenter)
            .title("COIT")
            .snippet("Bus Stop")
            .flat(true));

    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                    // call an activity(xml file)
                    Intent I = new Intent(this, BusInfo.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                }

            });
```

Comment: Please explain **completely and precisely** what "no luck" means.

Comment: It gives me this error. "The constructor Intent(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener(){}, Class<BusInfo>) is undefined" The quick fix would be "remove arguments to match Intent()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Intent I = new Intent(this, BusInfo.class);
```

with:

```
Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BusInfo.class);
```